# Retrieve a single value from a google query in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to retrieve in Python a specific value from a google query. In more details I need to ask google the number of inhabitants of a given city and/or its area so the query looks like: "number of inhabitants of NY, USA" and/or "area in km2 of NY, USA".
Looking on the internet I came up with this:

```
  try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found") 
  

query = "number of inhabitants of NY, USA"
  
for j in search(query, tld="com", num=10, stop=10, pause=2): 
    print(j)
```

but this code gives me the URLs of the website found by the query. I just need the actual value of the area or inhabitants of a given city. I am pretty confused by the different packages like BeautifulSoup4, google, googlesearch etc. I am not asking here a step-by-step solution to this problem but just where I can find a solution. Thank you

Comment: There are geo APIs that can provide this information in a better way.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+inhabitants+of+NY%2C+USA

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the source in the search **number of inhabitants of NY, USA** there are few CSS element that are not automatically generated.

When you are in the browser's developer tool (**F12**), if you use the inspection tool (**shift + alt + c** or **cmd+shift+c** on mac) you can see a parent div with an attribute **data-attrid** and value **dc:/legacy:location_statistical_region_population**

and the actual value of population is in a div with an attribute **aria-level='3'**

These are pretty random values and are subject to change. Also these values only work for population searches. But still we can chain them together to do our selection. In console (in Javascript) it goes like this:

```
document.querySelector("div[data-attrid='dc:/legacy:location_statistical_region_population']").querySelector("div[aria-level='3']")
```

In python you can execute javascript while you are simulating a browser i.e. using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("https://YOUR_SEARCH_URL")
print(driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector("div[data-attrid='dc:/legacy:location_statistical_region_population']").querySelector("div[aria-level='3']").textContent"""))
```

Note: as pointed out in comments, doing this using Google API instead of webscraping is the safest way. All of these html attributes are subject to change and probably Google wants to go the extra mile to not let you scrape this data this way